# How can I get my permalinks working when uploading the database to a localhost?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, permalinks

I've been working on my localhost machine developing my wordpress site, and I'm going to export the database and import it to another localhost on another machine. The thing is, I've tried it already and when lets say you click on about it gives a 404 error not found in database. I'm using custom permalink structure /%postname%/

But when in the new localhost I change the custom to default it works. I don't want to /p?=123 at the end of my URL since I already have my links set up. Was wondering how I can set up the links to work?

Comment: preferably in the .htaccess file because its going to be turned in to a instructor and I'm sure they wouldn't want to go through the trouble to edit some file on their machine for my project

Answer (score 3):

you need to click on the wamp server, choose the apache menu -> apache modules then move the menu down and choose rewrite_module. You will need the server to restart for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess file is writable and mod_rewrite is enabled, WordPress will insert this code when you change the permalink structure.  If it is not writable, WordPress will let you know to copy and past this code into the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```